# How to copy a directory folder from local drive to WAMP www folder

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver, copy-paste, directory

I haven't used `WAMP` in a while, but I need to use it to test some ajax.  I already have a folder on my local drive and I was hoping I could just copy my local directory into the `www` folder on `WAMP`.  However, when I try to copy/paste or drag and drop the folder into `www` on `WAMP`, the folder doesn't show up.  I get the dialog window of the copy action progress, but when it's done, the file is **not** in the `www` folder on `WAMP`.  As a workaround, I have opened files up in Atom editor from my local directory, and done a **SAVE AS** to save the file into a folder I created in `www` on `WAMP`.  That seems to work, but I have alot of files and I didn't want to have to do this for each file.  Please let me know how to do this. I have googled and searched SO, but I can't seem to find the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: When you say you're copying to www on WAMP, are you browsing to the physical path in file explorer on your computer?

Comment: Yes.  I am using Windows explorer on WIN 7 Professional.  Thanks

Comment: ... and when you say you can't see them, are you browsing to the folder in a browser, or is it when you browse using file explorer? Might be a stupid suggestion, but if it's the first have you tried turning WAMP off and on?

Comment: @DanGardner, what I'm doing is browsing to the my local folder in windows explorer, right-clicking the folder I want to copy to www on WAMP, select "copy" then browsing to www folder on WAMP and right-ciicking within www, select "paste".  the Copy dialog box appears to show progress.  I haven't tried turning WAMP on and off.  I'll try that

Comment: Yeah try that, post back with the results! Might also be worth a full computer reboot, sound stupid but often works!

Comment: tried stopping and starting WAMP, the folder is still not there.  I'm using my work computer, and I have Admin rights.  It seems to be going through the paste process, but the folder doesn't show up.  Ok, I'll try a reboot.  SO is telling me I should take this discussion to "chat" instead of having extended conversations!

Comment: Reboot didn't work.

Comment: There is nothing about WAMPServer that would stop you copying file into the `\wamp\www\` folder. So it must be something odd about your system. Did you install WAMPServer "As an Administrator"

Comment: Yes, I did.  My solution was to save each file individually into the www WAMP folder using my text editor.  Could be a bug in the .exe or something?  I'm unable to download from the wamp website, I must use my company's enterprise repository of approved applications since I work in the financial industry.